# How to distinguish between deformation mechanisms in creep experiment?

Tags: defects, stress-strain

As I'm learning more about viscoelasticity and creep experiments, I'm trying to understand how to distinguish between the different deformation mechanisms.
In general, when a sample of viscoelastic material is being deformed - there are few regimes: elastic, anelastic, and steady-state creep.
The deformation in the anelastic and steady-state are mainly due to the motion of defects (point defects, dislocations and grain boundaries).
Hypothetically, what would be the way to know which of the defects is behind the deformation? Is there a way to distinguish between them (I know they can happen simultaneously, but one might be more dominant)

(I wasn't sure if I should post this question here or in Physics)

Comment: I think the question would be on topic here, though there is a chance that you would get a quicker answer on Physics or Engineering SE. If you do decide you want to move the question, let me know and I can migrate it one of those sites rather than needing to delete it here and repost it separately.

Comment: Have you figured this out now? Please update us!

Comment: If the question is still of interest and you have any updates, let us know. We periodically go through unanswered questions to see if we can resolve them, but if they aren't of interest to the user any more, we tend to close them so we can manage the unanswered questions that are still actively seeking answers.

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.